# How to render aspxgridview responsive webdesign

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to render aspxgridview in responsive web design. How can i achieve responsive aspxgridview i have tried with footable(
http://techbrij.com/asp-net-gridview-responsive-jquery-footable) but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post, but I have recently implemented FooTable with an asp.net GridView, what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Hi Tom, FooTable is working fine with the normal asp.net Gridview no issues in that. But i am using third party GridView(devexpress aspxGridview) Control instead of normal asp.net GridView. I have modified your plugin accordingly aspxgridview.rendering method. actually they are rendering GridView in the following way:
<table><tr>

Comment: FYI: I have modified your plugin accordingly aspxgridview rendering. It is working fine with your older version. I have some few more issues with your newer version plugin. I am trying to fix those issues. One ce i complete with my issue fixes. i will contribute your modified plugin to you on gethub. Thanks RamaSubbaReddy M